# CRM Dynamics plugin code issue 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to create a plugin for Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2015 (version 7.0.2), but it's not working.
The plugin will run when a case is created and will attemp to recover the Contract information from the account.

I have the following code, it's not working(contract information is not saved on the case/incident).

### Edit

I update my code, now it fails, but it doesn't give a clear error on the system job or when i debug using the Plugin Registration Tool.

System job error message: System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #1C10449A

Debuging with Visual Studio and the Plugin Registration Tool it goes well until it tries to call the Update method, where it says that the incident does not exist, but since it was a syncrhonous plugin the incident was not created(only way to get the log to be able to debug that i found).

```
public class CaseContractFill : IPlugin
{
    Contract checkForContract(Guid accountId, IOrganizationService service)
    {

        QueryExpression accountContractQuery = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = Contract.EntityLogicalName,
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions = 
                {
                    new ConditionExpression 
                    {
                        AttributeName = "accountid",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = { accountId }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        DataCollection<Entity> accountContracts = service.RetrieveMultiple(accountContractQuery).Entities;

        //Check if account has a contract and return it
        if (accountContracts.Count > 0)
        {
            return (Contract)accountContracts[0];
        }

        //Retrieves account
        Account account = (Account)service.Retrieve(Account.EntityLogicalName, accountId, new ColumnSet(true));

        //Check if account has a parent and call this method again with that parent
        if (account.ParentAccountId != null)
        {
            checkForContract(account.ParentAccountId.Id, service);
        }

        //If no Contract and/or no Parent returns null
        return null;

    }

    ContractDetail checkForContractLine(Guid contractId, IOrganizationService service)
    {
        QueryExpression accountContractQuery = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = ContractDetail.EntityLogicalName,
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions = 
                {
                    new ConditionExpression 
                    {
                        AttributeName = "contractid",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = { contractId }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        DataCollection<Entity> contractLines = service.RetrieveMultiple(accountContractQuery).Entities;

        return (ContractDetail)contractLines[0];
    }

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];                
            Incident incident = (Incident)entity.ToEntity<Incident>();

            Contract contract = checkForContract(incident.CustomerId.Id, service);

            if (contract != null)
            {
                incident.ContractId = contract.ToEntityReference();

                ContractDetail contractLine = checkForContractLine(contract.Id, service);
                incident.ContractDetailId = contractLine.ToEntityReference();

                service.Update(incident);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I create a new case/incident but it doesn't add the contract it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ContractId" is being incorrectly assigned.

```
if (contract != null)
{
  incident.ContractId = contract.ToEntityReference();
  service.Update(incident);
}
```

Comment: Contract entity object must be null then, did you try to debug to see if contract has a value? or to do a quick and dirty check add an else condition to the above block and throw an exception.

Comment: I can't see to make the debug work, the error on the System job is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: checkForContract(incident.AccountId.Id, service); --> Are you sure AccountId is not null? This would be the only place I see you could get an object reference error.

Comment: Yes, it was null, i found the correct Id, but now i can't update, i edit my question with the changes to the code

Comment: How is the plugin registered? On Create ? Synchronous? Or any other message?

Comment: It's on the Create, Asynchronous, today i needed to restart my machine, so i removed the Profiler option from the plugin registration tool, after that the plugin started to work!
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`account.contract_customer_accounts` will be empty when you fetch the entity via `IOrganizationService.Retrieve`, just as all other relationships will be.

You could make a separate call to the service to fetch the related contracts with RetrieveMultiple, or you could look into using the [OrganizationServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328029.aspx).

Comment: Can you give me a help with the RetrieveMultiple, i don't now how to create the query or explain how i retrieve the information from the OrganizationServiceContext, i can't see that on the msdn link.